# Jquery TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[@href^= ""] img').parent().click(function () {
            var linkz = $(this).attr("href");
            if(linkz.toLowerCase().indexOf("http: //www.website.com") >= 0) {
                window.open($(this).attr("href"));
                return false;
            } else {
                window.open("http://www.website.com/p/img.html?img=" + $(this).attr("href "));
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

To open all images in a new page passing the image url in the new link. but i'm getting

> `TypeError: $ is not a function.`

I've tried to add jQuery(document) instead of the $(document) but then i got the

> `$(&#39;a[@href^=&quot;&quot;] img&#39;)` TypeError: $ is not a function

here.

Comment: '$ is not a function' is usually a sure sign that you've forgotten to include the jquery library

Comment: How did you include jQuery into the page?

Answer (score 1):

Either you didn't include jQuery, or else you ran noConflict() and it released control of $.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

If you used noConflict, you just need to use jQuery() throughout, including jQuery('a[@href^=""] img').

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not including jQuery correctly as the browser doesn't know what `$` is. Make sure you include something like this in `<head>` to include jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you havent added the jquery add this at `<head></head>`

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

**if you are testing locally , and you have a llow bandwith , then download the script one time ** 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js **to your folder** and
use 
  `<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
        function readyFn() {
            // Set your code here!!
        }

        $(document).ready(readyFn); 
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

**Or in your case:**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
        function readyFn() {
             $('a[@href^= ""] img').parent().click(function () {
             var linkz = $(this).attr("href");
             if(linkz.toLowerCase().indexOf("http: //www.website.com") >= 0) {
                 window.open($(this).attr("href"));
                 return false;
             } else {
                 window.open("http://www.website.com/p/img.html?img=" + $(this).attr("href"));
                 return false;
             }
        });
        }

        $(document).ready(readyFn); 
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```